# Is there a way to get paths of all the images of CAmera roll

Tags: iphone, camera

Is there any way to create an array or something

having paths of all the images stored in camera roll.

Please enlighten me on this.

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 2):

SpyPhone uses a direct path to the users photo library:

http://github.com/nst/spyphone/

It seems that any application can read it.  However, this seems like falls under the area of "undocumented API" and could well be rejected in a real application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is. As far as the API is concerned for the UIImagePickerController you can only get a single path for a Movie that was recorded by the user (if running 3.0 on a 3GS). And even that path is a file URL to the temporary folder where the movie is stored before being written to the library.

You can't get paths for any images in the photo library or the camera roll.

When you pick an image using the UIImagePickerController the controller returns the Original Image and an "Edited Image" if the image was edited before being chosen.